# how to retrieve a key in the object of my state and pass it as a parameter in another view?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I would like to recover the firebase key of my item in the object of my state and transfer it to another view via to a parameter in order to use it to add another item corresponding to this object in my database. firebase data.
when I put key: snapshot.key in my state my items are no longer displayed and I can not transmit it to another view in an object that contains the data of my positions. I do not know if I'm clear. but in my state I pass the object to it with the data and the key which I then store in a variable but it doesn't work.

```
export default class PostesMig extends React.Component {
    constructor () {
        super()

        this.state = {
            loading: true
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const ref = firebase.database().ref('PostesMig')

        ref.on('value', snapshot => {
            this.setState({
                postes : {
                data : snapshot.val(),
                key : snapshot.key,
                },
                loading: false
            })
        })
    }


    goToTorchesAir = (item) => this.props.navigation.navigate('Torches', {torches: item.TorchesMigRefroidiesAir, previous:'PostesMig'})
    goToTorchesEau = (item) => this.props.navigation.navigate('Torches', {torches: item.TorchesMigRefroidiesEau, previous:'PostesMig'})

    render() {

        if(this.state.loading) {
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text>Chargement...</Text>
                    <ActivityIndicator size="large"></ActivityIndicator>
                </View>
            )
        }  

        const list = this.state.postes




        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
            <ScrollView style={styles.scrollView}>
                <FlatList
                    data={list}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.Id.toString()}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <View>
                        <Card
                        title={item.DesignationAS400}
                        >
                            <Text style={{marginBottom: 10}}>
                                Code Commun : {item.CodeCommun}
                            </Text>
                            <Text style={{marginBottom: 10}}>
                                Réference Fournisseur : {item.RefFournisseur}
                            </Text>

                            <Button
                            onPress={this.goToTorches}pour onPress={()=>this.goToTorchesAir(item)}
                            buttonStyle={{borderRadius: 0, marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0, marginBottom: 0}}
                            title='VOIR LES TORCHES AIR' />
                            {item.TorchesMigRefroidiesEau  !== undefined &&
                            <Button
                            onPress={this.goToTorches}pour onPress={()=>this.goToTorchesEau(item)}
                            buttonStyle={{borderRadius: 0, marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0, marginBottom: 0, marginTop: 4}}
                            title='VOIR LES TORCHES EAU' />
                            }
                            <Button
                            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("AddTorche", {torches: item})}
                            buttonStyle={{borderRadius: 0, marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0, marginBottom: 0, marginTop: 4}}
                            title='AJOUTER UNE TORCHE' />
                            <Button
                            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("delPoste", {torches: item})}
                            buttonStyle={{borderRadius: 0, marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0, marginBottom: 0, marginTop: 4}}
                            title='MODIFIER LE POSTE' />
                            <Button
                            onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("updatePoste", {torches: item})}
                            buttonStyle={{borderRadius: 0, marginLeft: 0, marginRight: 0, marginBottom: 0, marginTop: 4}}
                            title='SUPPRIMER LE POSTE' />
                        </Card>
                    </View>
                    )}
                    />
            </ScrollView>
            <View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("AddPoste")}>
                   <Text>Ajouter un poste</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.button} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate("Home")}>
                   <Text>Retour</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>

            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: As far as I can see, your code is not using the `key` that you put in the state. Where do you expect it to be used?

Comment: Sorry if I do not use the right tags I am also a beginner on stack overflow I do not yet know the good practices of the forum.
I would like to store it in this.state.postes so that I can pass it to my next view in parameters

Comment: You **are** already storing the key in the state here: `key : snapshot.key,`. You're just not using it anywhere yet as far as I can see. Did you try using `postes.key` in your `render method`